# memoir and standalone package

Tags: memoir, enumerate, standalone

My main document is based on `memoir` documentclass. For inclusion of figures I use `standalone` package. It collaborate fine. But I have problem, how to include in figures (using `standalone` document class), that it can use some `memoir` specific formatting of document? Something like:

```
\docummentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{????} %this should somehow incorporate memoir formatting
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   ....
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For example, memoir has somehow modified enumerate environment. If I use for exmple

```
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
\item some text
\end{enumerate}
```

gives error "item missing". Beside above example there are more cases of formatting which I like to use also in some pictures. How to do this since `memoir` can not be included as document style (package)?

Comment: that is the functionality from the `enumerate` package, I'd rather recommend using `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` as it provides more features. Why do you need the `standalone` for the inclusion of figures when your main doc is `memoir` based?

Comment: I use standalone for inclusion of pictures. With standalone package I'm able to draw picture without to compile whole document. the second reason is probably even more important: with standalone i create set of pictures, which can anyone (read: my students) included as pdf files in their document (if they liked). On the another hand, I'm quit familiar with memoir and I'm not very keen to use additional package to the memoir, which functionality are already somehow incorporated in the memoir.

Comment: Trust me you will want to learn `enumitem`, there are many things regarding lists that memoir does not provide interfaces to, `enumitem` do

Comment: I check packages enumitem and also enumerate. Indeed, the enumitem has nice capabilities for formatting of lists. The enumerate has number of preformatted lists, which are more close tho memoir combination \begin{enumerate}\firmlist, so I decide to mimic memoir lists in my tikz pictures with paralist. Thank you to give me idea, how I can mimic some meoir specific formating with other more specialized packages.

Comment: In standalone class you need to use a minipage or tabular to handle more than one line of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `standalone` class loads by default the `article` class internally, which can be changed using the `class=<name>` option.

If you want to put your `enumerate` environment inside a `tikzpicture` `\node` then you need also add the `text width=<value>` option so that the node can hold paragraph material. Otherwise you will get the same `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` as when `class=memoir` is missing!

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,class=memoir]{standalone}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [text width=10em] at (0,0) {%
       \begin{enumerate}[1.]
            \item some text
            \item some text
        \end{enumerate}%
    };
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. i hope that it will help to someone. i figured out this almost four years ago but in this time i wasn't aware that i can answer on my question :-(. anyway, +1 and i was accept it too.